# Having issues prototyping account creation in iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have been learning iOS development since august and I am just now starting to develop my first app. Before I even remotely know how to develop my app I have been creating small prototype  apps with MINIMAL functionality just to understand how to do one part of my actual product. Right now I am stuck on a project that simply creates an account and stores it in an array for later usage i.e. displaying data model object and its various properties on a "my profile" page;

To be more specific I am simply trying to understand how to (at the most basic "bare-bones" level) take inputed info (username, password, full name) from the user, translate it into my data model object, then store that object into an array of objects of the same type and finally display the data model object on a profile page. I am using this to understand what a part of the general architecture of the app is going to look like.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Account  {
    var username: String
    var password: String
    var fullName: String
    
    static var accounts: [Account] = []
    
    init(username: String, password: String, fullName: String) {
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.fullName = fullName
    }
}
```

My data model file Account.swift

```
import UIKit

class RegisterViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var usernameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var passwordField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var fullNameField: UITextField!
    
    var newAccount = Account(username: "", password: "", fullName: "")
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    @IBAction func createAccount(_ sender: UIButton) {
        newAccount.username = usernameField.text!
        newAccount.password = passwordField.text!
        newAccount.fullName = fullNameField.text!
        
        Account.accounts.append(newAccount)
    }
```

my view controller for the register view

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: RegisterViewController {

    @IBOutlet var usernameLogin: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var passwordLogin: UITextField!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    @IBAction func loginToProfile(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if usernameLogin.text! == newAccount.username {
            print("success")
        } else {
            print("error")
        }
        
        if passwordLogin.text! == newAccount.password {
            print("success")
        } else {
            print("error")
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func unwindToLogin(unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue)  {
        
    }

}
```

my veiw controller for the login view.

[image]

the top would be the view to make an account where as the bottom is the login view. My issue right now is via my if statements in the login vc, my console outputs error indicating the strings dont match after I attempted to register an account then login with it.

I am aware that I force-unwrapped all the uitextfield optionals didnt think that affected much in this specific case. Nonetheless if there are any other blaring issues feel free to point them out

Comment: What's the point of making an account like `var newAccount = Account(username: "", password: "", fullName: "")`?

Comment: To create an Account instance to store and reuse the users info. Feel free to completely school me lol. It wont let me create an account instance with out providing some default initilized values. I guess I should create a custom initilizer for the class but idk if that will make a difference. Havent tried it yet. Like I said this whole thing could be completely wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what it looks, you have 2 different controllers: `RegisterViewController` and another `ViewController`, which, although it subclasses `RegisterViewController`, is not the same *instance*. So when you fill in `newAccount` in `RegisterViewController`, it doesn't mean you are filling in `newAccount` inside `ViewController`.

What you should do, is instead to *look for* matching account in `Account.accounts`, and compare its properties to the one provided by a user, i.e.:

```
@IBAction func loginToProfile(_ sender: UIButton) {

    // Find the right account
    guard let account = Account.accounts.filter { $0.username == usernameLogin.text! } else {
        print("Error: No such account")
        return
    }

    // Now check if passwords match
    guard account.password == passwordLogin.text! else {
        print("Error: incorrect password")
        return
    }
```

Note: this is just minimal change to get you unstuck. But really, I would do some other changes:

1. There's no reason for `ViewController` to subclass `RegisterViewController` - they are different view controllers, they share *information*, but they are completely different in their functional purpose.
2. I would make `Account` a `struct`, that represents a single account. While  `static var accounts: [Account] = []` should be in some other class, that holds all the accounts, and, in the future, retrieves them from elsewhere. Simplest form of [MVC](https://www.raywenderlich.com/477-design-patterns-on-ios-using-swift-part-1-2#toc-anchor-002) pattern or an `Accounts` singleton for now will do. Later you can improve on that part, while `struct Account` will probably remain unchanged.
3. Second change would also allow you to change the way you compare accounts: instead of function above, you could do something like (many variations possible, giving just 1 example, which assumes you have a singleton which holds all accounts)

   ```
   @IBAction func loginToProfile(_ sender: UIButton) {

       Accounts.shared.login(username: usernameLogin.text!, password: passwordLogin.text!)
   ```

   which would allow you to completely abstract *how* user is validated from your view controller